# Virtual application name in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I installed an ASP.NET Core application under a Virtual application name. The URL of the site is the following:

```
http://10.0.0.253/ApplicationName/
```

The problem is that all the redirects and static files path ignore the application name. If I have the following line in my razor file:

```
<link href="~/css/Custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The output will be http://10.0.0.253/css/Custom.css instead of http://10.0.0.253/ApplicationName/css/Custom.css

The problem is that this application will be executed under a lot of different Virtual Applications which means that I cannot fix the URL by typing the correct URL because depending on the application which will be executed, the generated URL will be different.
In ASP.NET MVC 5 I could get the virtual application name using the following code:

```
string VPath = Request.ApplicationPath;
```

Is there a way to get this value in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: This is role for your reverse proxy, not application (except you using only Kestrel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways you can resolve your problem (via code, as noted, there may be other resolutions via infrastructure):

1. Using the [`Url.Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routing.urlhelper.content?view=aspnetcore-2.0) method:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/css/Custom.css")" />
```

2. Using a [`LinkTagHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers.linktaghelper?view=aspnetcore-2.0) (e.g. by specifying the `asp-append-version` attribute `true` or `false`):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/Custom.css" asp-append-version="true" />
```